# mongodb find with calculated field

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to create a mongodb query using the filtered value in the filter. For example:

```
   var myIdVariable = '1jig23h34r34r30h';
   var myVisibleVariable = false;
   var myDistanceVariable = 100;

   db.getCollection.find({
        '_id': myIdVariable,
        'isVisible': myVisibleVariable,
        'distanceRange': {$lte: {myDistanceVariable - distanceRange}}
    })
```

So, I want filter the distanceRange from database based on the calculation of (myDistanceVariable - distanceRange), with the distanceRange given in the same query.
I don't know if I give you a clear explanation of my problem. It's possible?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **[`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/)** operator to build a query expression that allows you to compare fields from the same document as well as compare the `distanceRange` field with the calculation of  the field itself and your variables.

You would need to use the logical **[`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#op._S_and)** query operator to include the other query expressions thus your final query would look like the following:

```
db.getCollection('collectionName').find({
    '$expr': {
        '$and': [
            { 'isVisible': myVisibleVariable },
            { '$lte': [
                '$distanceRange', {
                    '$subtract': [
                        myDistanceVariable, '$distanceRange'
                    ]
                }
            ] }
        ]
    }
})
```

---

If your MongoDB server doesn't support the **[`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/)** operator then go for the aggregation framework route with **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/)**

```
db.getCollection('collectionName').aggregate([
    { "$redact": {
        "$cond": [
            {   
                '$and': [
                    { 'isVisible': myVisibleVariable },
                    { '$lte': [
                        '$distanceRange', {
                            '$subtract': [
                                x, '$distanceRange'
                            ]
                        }
                    ] }
                ]
            },
            "$$KEEP",
            "$$PRUNE"
        ]
    } }
])
```

**Note**

Including the `_id` in the query expressions means you are narrowing down your selection to just a single document and the query may not return any results since it's looking for a specific document with that `_id` AND the same document should satisfy the other query expressions.